# Empty data from database

Tags: php

HI i have this code here ,, it's For Login system :

```
elseif($_GET['action'] == "login"){
if(!empty($_GET['user_name']) && !Empty($_GET['password'])){
    session_name('Huemix|Studio');
    session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
    sec_session_start();
    $user = sql_safe($_GET['user_name']);
    $pass = sql_safe($_GET['password']);
    $rem = sql_safe($_GET['rememberMe']);
    if(!count($err)){
        $sql = sprintf("SELECT loginid FROM login WHERE username='%s' AND password = '%s'",$user,md5($pass));
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
        if(!$query){
            echo mysql_error();
        }else{
            echo $row["username"];
            echo $row["loginid"];
            //echo $user;
           // echo $pass;
        }
        if($row['username']){
            $sql = sprintf("UPDATE login SET last_login='".time()."' WHERE username = '%s' AND password = '%s' ",$user,md5($pass));
            $query = mysql_query($sql);
            if($query){
                $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
                $_SESSION['id'] = $row['loginid'];
                $_SESSION['rememberMe'] = $rem;
                setcookie("HuemixRemember",$rem);
                header("Location : index.php");
            }
            echo '<p style="color: #ff0000;">Error in Login system ,, Please Call The Programmer !</p>';
        }else{
            echo '<p style="color: #ff0000;">Error in Username and/or Password !</p>';
        }
    }
}else{
    echo '<p style="color: #ff0000;">All Fields are Required !</p>';
}
```

}

now i did some safety function to my script and they are :
sec_session_start();
And 
sql_safe();
Here is there codes :
sec_session_start();

```
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; // Set a custom session name
    $secure = false; // Set to true if using https.
    $httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id. 

    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies. 
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
    session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_start(); // Start the php session
    session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerated the session, delete the old one.
```

}

And sql_safe():

```
function sql_safe($value){
if ( $value ){
    $value = strip_tags($value);
    $value = htmlspecialchars($value); 
    $value = trim($value);
    $value = stripslashes($value);
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    return $value;
}
else{
    return false;
}
```

}

Now My problem is in the line `echo $row["username"];` 
There is no data printed ,, and i'm sure that there is a data in database and the connection works fine with the database 
and i tried to do `echo $user;` to see if the error from the values that Interred from the input box ,, but the output was the same as i interred !

So i really i don't know what happened !!!
Always showing the error `Error in Login system ,, Please Call The Programmer !`
that caused by the if statement `if($row['username']){` !!

another question please :
Can you please tell me a tips or codes to secure my script ,, in everything " login, logout, sessions, cookies ... etc "

And thanks ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not selecting username in your select statement which is why it cannot be used - add username to your select statement when you choose your fields.

```
    SELECT loginid,username FROM login WHERE username='%s'...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be, that you do not SELECT the username:

`$sql = sprintf("SELECT loginid FROM login WHERE username='%s' AND password = '%s'",$user,md5($pass));`

Should be:

`$sql = sprintf("SELECT username, loginid FROM login WHERE username='%s' AND password = '%s'",$user,md5($pass));`

Answer (score 0):

```
       }
        echo '<p style="color: #ff0000;">Error in Login system ,, Please Call The Programmer !</p>';
```

Should probably be

```
       } else {
           echo '<p style="color: #ff0000;">Error in Login system ,, Please Call The Programmer !</p>';
       }
```

right now you're simply outputting that error message, ignoring entirely the query results.